# CKEditor for asp.net - alignment not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor.net

I'm brand new as asking questions, so I thank you for your patience.

After using FreeTextBox for years, we are moving to CKEditor.  We work on Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2013 in C#, .NET Framework 4.5.  I installed the ASP.NET version of CKEditor runtime version v2.0.50727 and it's working fine on the localhost except for one thing:  clicking on any alignment, Left, Center or right, does not put a HTML code in the text.

Does anybody have any idea why I'm getting this behaviour?  Should I use a Custom button?  I've seen this question posted elsewhere, but not using that ASP.NET version.

Edit:  I just discovered I'm not getting an HTML code when I try to create a bulleted list either.. am I missing a format function?

Comment: Is there any reason you use CKEditor control instead of just invoking `CKEDITOR.replace()` in JavaScript? Also it looks like your version is quite old. The current version of CKEditor control for ASP.NET is 3.6.6.2 (which also is quite old).

Comment: Thank you so much kfazi.. I need to find the more current version and install it.  I use, but am not completely comfortable with JavaScript so I generally avoid it.

Comment: Also.. I finally figured it out to this point anyway.. by adding "config.extraAllowedContent = '*{*}';" and "config.allowedContent = true;" to config.js, HTML tags WITH their amounts are now being added.